# Wildfly 29 - War artifact doesn't work in a Remote Virtual Machine but it does in a local environment

Tags: java, centos, wildfly, war, jaas

I have a wildfly 29 built in my local environment, with Windows 11 in which I deploy an application that logs in through JAAS and if the login is successful it redirects me to the application, everything works OK at this environment.

I have the same wildly 29 with exactly the same configuration in a virtual machine with Centos, I deploy exactly the same artifact but on this server when I try to log in, although it recognizes the users (since if it is wrong I get the message of incorrect credentials) it does not redirects me to the application, it redirects me to the same login page, I don't get any errors in the browser console or in the wildfly log, what could it be? Thank you so much.